# What does "~から~" mean in "覚めてからその後寝られず"?

Tags: meaning, particle-から

Context:

> 今朝は5時半に目が覚めて**からその後**寝られず、一日中眠たかったです。

What does "から" mean in this context?

If it means "after/later", are "から" and "その後" repetitious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate から as "since" and その後 as "after that" or "thereafter." It is redundant. "I woke up at 5:30 and from then on couldn't get back to sleep. I was sleepy all day."